# PRAW Requesting All Subreddit Posts: Receive 401 Error

Tags: python-3.x, praw, reddit

I'm trying to grab every single post from a subreddit all the way back to it's beginning in 2010, specifically /r/nosleep.

My code for grabbing those posts is the usual:

```
for submission in nosleep.submissions(end=int(time.time()):
```

It works perfectly, I've checked my credentials they all work, and it will easily grab two years worth of posts without any issue.  What happens is I run the above for loop, and at some point around the end, it returns a 401 and crashes the entire program.

I've checked and confirmed the following scenarios:

- It will grab from 2010 to 2011, no problem with it hitting the "start" of the subreddit and thinking it's forbidden to grab posts before the subreddit began.
- I've printed out `reddit.auth.limits` on each loop, and they all respond with `None`, so I'm not running out of request allowances.

The only "hack" around this is to split up the work into two for loops, splitting `int(time.time())` into two (or more) pieces and iterating over each like this:

```
for submission in nosleep.submissions(start=middle, end=int(time.time())):
for submission in nosleep.submissions(end=middle):
```

Even then, it sometimes returns a 401.  I suspect it's because of the length of time this loop is running, but I don't know.  Does anyone have any suggestions for a new method, or editing the PRAW source to accommodate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the latest development version of PRAW (`pip install --upgrade https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/archive/master.zip`) as this issue *should* be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For future Googlers, this issue can also be caused after getting the password wrong multiple times. It takes about 20 minutes to reset, then it will work again.